# Proving a PDE has a particular weak form (check my proof please!)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $u_t - \Delta u = f$ hold in $L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ for a solution $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0)$ with $u_t \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$.

This means
$$\int_0^T \left(\langle u_t(t), v(t)\rangle + \int_\Omega \nabla u(t) \nabla v(t)\right) = \int_0^T\langle f(t), v(t) \rangle$$
for all $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$.

I want to show that this implies 
$$\langle u_t(t), v(t) \rangle+ \int_\Omega \nabla u(t) \nabla v(t) = \langle f(t), v(t) \rangle\tag{*}$$
for almost all $t$ and for all $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$.

To get this, pick $v(t) = \psi(t)w(t)$ where $\psi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$ and $w \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$. Then we will get

$$\int_0^T \psi(t)\left(\langle u_t(t), w(t)\rangle + \int_\Omega \nabla u(t) \nabla w(t)\right) = \int_0^T\psi(t)\langle f(t), w(t) \rangle$$
Since $\psi$ is arbitrary, we conclude (*). Is it correct? I am not sure I am allowed to pick $v=\psi w$ like that where $\psi$ is arbitrary...

I am also doubting about the null set. Is it problematic if it depends on the test function?

Comment: Hmm, isn't the problem with the null sets to do with $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0)$? Separability of $C_c^\infty$ does not seem to be relevant? Do you have source for the separability argument, I have not seen it yet.

Comment: From your last equality: You can approximate a piecewise linear continuous function that vanishes at $0$, $T$ with $\psi$, and eventually conclude that the integrals are equal over every interval $[a,b]\subset (0,T)$, where $\psi$ is replace by $1$. And that gives you what you want a.e. $t$ by differentiating with respect to the upper limit $b$.

Comment: @T.A.E. I agree that it gives me the equality. But the problem is the null sets.. the equality we want holds a.e. but the null set may depend on the test function.

Comment: Since $\psi$ was arbitrary, you can conclude by the du Bois-Reymond lemma that your desired equation holds indeed.

Comment: @Chinese_Guy : I see your issue now. The problem is that (*) is not correctly stated if you want the same execeptional subset $E\subset[0,T]$ in $t$ for all $v \in L^{2}[0,T;H^1)$. You should say: there is a set $E$ of Lebesgue measure $0$ in $[0,T]$ such that the equation holds for all $t \in [0,T]\setminus E$ and all $v \in L^{2}[0,T;H^{1}]$. Is that what you mean? By the way, that's not going to happen because of the ambiguity in $v$.

Comment: @T.A.E. You are right. Please see my new thread if you are so inclined, it is about this topic which is subtle for me.!!!